# Is it possible to access other files through the NSApplicationDelegate

Tags: objective-c

first of all: sorry for bad title, didn't knew how to tell my problem in one simple sentence :S

Well... here is my problem:

I have a NSWindow (declared and added in the ApplicationDelegate) inside that window i have to views. One named view1 and one named view2.

Both view1 and view2 is declared and added as subviews in NSApplicationDelegate.

In view2 things can happen (WOW!) that needs to be displayed in view1. how can i do this? :S

Fell free to ask any questions you may have =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communication between views should be done through controllers.

Have view2 notify it's controller when something happens. This controller can then communicate with the controller for view1 which then communicates the change to view1.

Comment: thanks for the answer =) got a link to some examples on this?

Comment: No. It's just a matter of wiring up what you know. You know how a view communicates changes to it's controller. You know how to send a message to an object, and you know how a controller communicates with it's view.